# ProgressDialog causes app to crash in android

Tags: android, progressdialog, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to create a simple CRUD application in android.

App is crashing whenever I login but internally it does logs me in. Same problem when I logout. I get an error on `progressDialog.dismiss()`.

Here is the code in Asynctask class:

```
    @Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
    super.onPreExecute();
    path = ctx.getString(R.string.url);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Signing In");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Validating your credentials!");
    //progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();
}
```

And here is my code in onPostExecute method:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(progressDialog!=null){
        if(progressDialog.isShowing()){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        progressDialog = null;
    }
     //some more code
}
```

I'm getting a window leak error at `progressDialog.show()` line and `IllegalArgumentException` error on `progressDialog.dismiss()` line.

Here is my activity log:

```
06-07 02:14:11.155 1828-1828/com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{2b714c45 V.E..... R......D 0,0-959,322} that was originally added here
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
                                                                                   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:271)
                                                                                   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                                                                                   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
                                                                                   at com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp.BackgroundUserLogoutTask.onPreExecute(BackgroundUserLogoutTask.java:56)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:591)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:539)
                                                                                   at com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp.DashboardFragment$4.onClick(DashboardFragment.java:61)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

06-07 02:14:12.447 1828-1828/com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp, PID: 1828
                                                                                java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{2b714c45 V.E..... R......D 0,0-959,322} not attached to window manager
                                                                                    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:396)
                                                                                    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:322)
                                                                                    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:116)
                                                                                    at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:341)
                                                                                    at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:324)
                                                                                    at com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp.BackgroundUserLogoutTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundUserLogoutTask.java:117)
                                                                                    at com.example.thadaninilesh.productapp.BackgroundUserLogoutTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundUserLogoutTask.java:35)
                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Please post full error log.

Comment: I have updated my question with the complete activity log... Please help me if possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the activity/fragment where you're showing your progressdialog is destroyed before the dialog is dismissed. So that gives you a crash with

```
IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView not attached to window manager
```

So before you finishing your activity, dismiss your progress dialog.